# The application is missing required files

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, dll

I created a C# application in Visual studio 2010 with C#. It is using some other DLL files. When I publish it using Build->Publish the Setup.exe file generated.

When I run this setup in another machine I get the error "Required Files Missing.". I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684059/creating-an-installation-setup-file-in-visual-studio-that-requires-a-certain-dll), but it did not take out issues.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235317%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) also did not help  because inside `New Project->Other Project Types->Setup and Deployment`,  `Setup Project` is not there. It is empty.

How can I solve this?

Comment: So when you run it elsewhere, you copy that dll as well? And your program still can't find it? Is the location correct?

Comment: Is this a ClickOnce application?

Comment: @MatthewWatson: err? sorry?

Comment: @System.Windows.Form I'll take that as a "no" then. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you run set up in another machine, publish folder of the application is needed to be present in that machine in the correct location.

In your case publish folder is not present.

Hence this kind of error is comming.

Paste publish folder from your machine where program is running sucessfully to another machine where you want to install the application.

Then, run the setup file, within that publish folder.

Then only you will overcome from this problem.

Publish folder contains all the necessary dlls and files, that application needs to run.

Comment: Application Files folder should have been added to Setup required files.

Answer (score 0):

When I've run into this, I've found that one or more referenced DLLs needed to be set to CopyLocal = true.

This affects click-once apps and installers.  If there is a chance that the file isn't already on a user's computer, you'll need to include it (or have them install it)

(Check redistribution licensing for the files)